# getting a list of all images in a document (including blobs)

Tags: javascript, browser

Getting a list of all images of a website sounds easy. In Chrome you can open the developer tools, open the "Application" tab and under `Frames > top > Images` you see a list of all images. In code this should be something similar to:

`for(var i = 0; i< document.images.length; i++){
  console.log(document.images[i].src)
}`

The problem: when you open e.g. [Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps/@52.5023935,13.3474374,15116m/data=!3m1!1e3) you'll notice some images have a `src` like `blob:https://www.google.de/65ce9e40-01bd-4ec7-ad85-6f0ead2497d8`. Notice the `blob` prefix. AFAIU they are internally created and not loaded from the network as such.

The question is - how can one still get access to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting those `img` tags with `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` is because Google Maps uses a `<canvas>` and renders those images directly into the canvas (using the [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method), there are no direct img tags that are part of the DOM.

For example take a look at [`this fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/jarfdphn/1/) in which the images are loaded using a blob but injected into an img tag (in this case you can successfully get them using `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`):

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png", true );

xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
    
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) { 
        console.log(images[i].src); 
    }   
};

xhr.send();
```

```html
<img id="photo"/>
```

In this case we can successfully loop through the image elements that are part of the DOM and display their src property.

Now take a look on the other hand [`the approach that Google Maps`](https://jsfiddle.net/mvwyom99/2/) uses with a `<canvas>` element:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open( "GET", "https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png", true );

xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
    
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) { 
        console.log(images[i].src); 
    }    
};

xhr.send();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" />
```

As you can see in this case nothing gets printed into the console because `document.querySelectorAll('img')` returns an empty array.

Unfortunately I am not quite sure how you can extract the images that have already been drawn into an existing canvas.

Comment: Good analysis. While they are available through the Developer Tools that doesn't necessarily mean they need to be accessible from javascript.

Comment: They are available through the Developer Tools because the images have been fetched through an AJAX request to the server, but the result of this request hasn't been added to an `<img>` tag but rather to a `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all images in your DOM by

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){alert(images.getAttribute("src"));}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){ console.log(images[i].getAttribute("src")) }` but no - that doesn't fly.